# Place Graphviz xlabel under the edge

Tags: graphviz

In Graphviz, are there options for:

- placing xlabel under an edge?
- setting transparency for an edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set transparency on (any?) color by specifying the color as an RGBA value, like so:

```
edge [color="#ff000080" penwidth=2]  // note translucent color
```